Android file/document picker not working properly
I have a device on Android 13. The file picker seems inconsistent when picking/selecting files from Android storage.
From the 1st screenshot, the file picker has the option to browse for files from storage using other file managers but not in the second case.








How to fix this anomaly?

Try scrolling up and down.
Those options "Gallery", "My Files", "Photos" and the other similar options than those that appear in your left screen should appear once you scroll down in the file picker.

They do not appear

@xavier_fakerat could you describe from what context you are opening those views that we see in each screenshot?

To reproduce when you whant to pick a file with a third-party program say to send a file it, the document picker only allows to browse with built-in documentui.
